# DataStax DevCenter Schema window is empty

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

After a successful connection, the Schema window in my DataStax DevCenter is always empty. There are no keyspaces. But it's wrong. I can see the keyspaces and tables on the server using cqlsh.

I have checked the error log and it contains nothing about it.

I use Cassandra 2.2.3.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

DevCenter is a proprietary tool from Datastax, that only works with Datastax enterprise, the current version supported is [5.0](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/devcenter/doc/devcenter/dcInstallation.html).

There are other providers, like [Hackolade](https://hackolade.com/nosqldb/cassandra-data-modeling.html) that can give you this functionality.

(Disclaimer, I am not an user of the tool I only saw a demo in the Datastax Accelerate convention)

Comment: You are wrong. I am familiar with this tool. It can work with Cassandra. I have the free edition of that tool which is included in the free Cassandra distribution package.

Comment: I agree, some years ago Datastax used to provide the tool that could be used with open source Cassandra distributions, the same as OpsCenter; but currently that is not the case anymore. Even in the pre-requisites page (https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/devcenter/doc/devcenter/dcUsingDevCenter.html) they mention that you'll need `A DataStax Enterprise cluster installed and running.`

Comment: It's not relevant in my case because I use an an old version of Cassandra and an old distribution package in the client.

Comment: I doubt that on Accelerate they did show the DevCenter. Most probably it was Studio that works only with DSE... But it's completely different product

Comment: The demonstration was for Hackolade; and you are right, they had different talks of Datastax studio

Answer (score 0):

You have to select your connection name in the "run using connection" menu if you can access it. In the .cql pallete you will see the schema.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwAhQ.png)